# UTF8mb4 encoding MySQL and PHP diagnosis for '€' symbol

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem extracting data from my MYSQL ***UTF8mb4_general_ci*** database with PHP as some characters (linke the '€' symbol and emojis) are not echoed correctly in the browser.

Here is the situation:

- the **database** is encoded in UTF8mb4_general_ci
- the **table** is encoded in UTF8mb4_general_ci
- the **column** is encoded in UTF8mb4_general_ci
- the **string** extracted from the record has been written straight
  from phpmyadmin
- **mysqli** encoding has been set to utf8mb4_general_ci

Here's the code:

```
mysqli_set_charset($db_connection,"utf8mb4_general_ci");
```

- strange fact: PHP **mb_detect_encoding**($string_from_db) does not return any value
- the **PHP script** is encoded in UTF8
- the **browser** displays correctly the '€' symbol echoed from php

For example:

```
echo('€'); // displays € correctly
```

- the browser does not display the '€' symbol echoed from the db

For example:

```
echo($db_value); //does not echo '€' but rather ?
```

- there is a **PHP header** specifying the content type is text/html UTF8
- the html is set to UTF8 through the **meta charset** tag

What am I missing?

I checked the other posts on stack overflow but they don't answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean exacly?

Comment: If you store a € from a PHP script do you get it back correctly from a select?

Comment: I stored it through phpmyadmin, and I don't get it back correctly (although it displays correctly inside phpmyadmin)

Comment: So write a quick INSERT in PHP and see what happens to the euro then

Comment: Ouch! it's messed up! adding the '€' symbol from PHP into the db shows some strange characters in phpmyadmin! How's that possible?

Comment: it's possible when you mess up some of the steps described in your post. Some of them are not the way you think they are

Comment: ah. I even know which one. UTF8mb4_general_ci is not encoding.

Comment: For further debugging help, see the `SELECT hex(col)` suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored